# How to remove extra space or new line in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

When I call an API I received an response as below

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "message": null,
  "responseBody": {
    "subject": "Task2",
    "emailContent": "",
    "emailContentTrail": "Hi ,\r\nReplying\r\nFrom Outlook\r\n\r\nIn multiple\r\nLines\r\n\r\nthanks you,\r\nSam \r\n________________________________\r\nFrom: Workflow,\r\nSent: Monday, April 5, 2021 12:01 PM\r\nTo: Workflow,\r\nCc: Sam \r\nSubject:Task2\r\n\r\nCAUTION: EXTERNAL EMAIL. Please do not reply, forward, or open links/attachments unless you recognize the sender.\r\n\r\nHi ,\r\n\r\nMultiple Line\r\n\r\nMessage Checking\r\n\r\n\r\nMessage\r\n\r\n\r\nThank you,\r\n\r\nSam \r\n\r\n\r\n________________________________\r\nTry to see whether extra space can be removed using css or regex pattern\r\n\r\n\r\nDisclaimer: The information contained in this e-mail and any accompanying documents may contain information that is confidential or otherwise protected from disclosure. If you are not the intended recipient of this message, or if this message has been addressed to you in error, please immediately alert the sender by reply e-mail and then delete this message, including any attachments. Any dissemination, distribution or other use of the contents of this message by anyone other than the intended recipient is strictly prohibited. Any comments or statements made are not necessarily those of Xceedance. All messages sent to and from this e-mail address may be monitored as permitted by applicable law and regulations to ensure compliance with our internal policies and to protect our business. E-mails are not secure and cannot be guaranteed to be error free as they can be intercepted, amended, lost or destroyed, or contain viruses. You are deemed to have accepted these risks if you communicate with us by e-mail.\r\n",
    "attachments": []
  },
  "page": null,
  "links": null,
  "error": false
}
```

I have to show the 'emailContentTrail' data in a textarea.
But I want to remove the additional new line which are present. How can I do that.
Currently the data are shown as follows
[image]

As you can see there is lot of white space between two texts. I want to remove that space.
How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `\r\n\r\n` to `\r\n`, you can use following regex:

```
emailContentTrail.replaceAll("(\r?\n){2,}", "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the new lines in the string with the following code:

```js
var originalText = "This is a test text and the next \n line will be removed!"
var removedNewLinesText = originalText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");


console.log(originalText);
console.log(removedNewLinesText);
```

Just use this method on the section you desire to delete.

Comment: I want to maintain the format,  but if there is two \n\n is present I want to remove only